# Please give me example of implicit and explicit type conversion in C#

Tags: c#, type-conversion, implicit-conversion

can any one give me implicit type conversion example in real life. I know implicit type conversion means conversion from derived to base class but i don't know how to show in coding in c#. I don't want to define it in 2 lines. I want to define a full program to show implicit and explicit type conversion in c#. Please help me.

Regards

Comment: This link is useful for type conversion and examples: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx

Answer (score 12):

No, implicit type conversion just means a type conversion which doesn't need to be explicit in the code.

LINQ to XML provides good examples:

```
// Implicit conversion from string to XNamespace
XNamespace ns = "http://url.com";

XElement element = new XElement("foo", "bar");
// Explicit conversion of XElement to string
string value = (string) element;
```

So that's how they're *used* - and you *create* your own explicit or implicit conversion operators using the kind of code shown in MSDN ([explicit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhbhezf4.aspx), [implicit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2.aspx)).

Short, complete, but pointless example:

```
class Foo
{
    private readonly int value;

    private Foo(int value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public static implicit operator Foo(int value)
    {
        return new Foo(value);
    }

    public static explicit operator int(Foo foo)
    {
        if (foo == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("foo");
        }
        return foo.value;
    }
}

class Test
{    
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int x = 10;
        Foo foo = x;
        int y = (int) foo;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Implicit** (This is just an example, there are other situations in which an object's type is implicitly converted.)

```
int f(Animal a) {...}

Elephant e; // Elephant is-a Animal
f(e);
```

**Explicit**

```
int f(Animal a) {...}

Alien someAlien; // Alien is-not-a Animal
f((Animal)someAlien); // Works only if conversion from Alien to Animal is user-defined.
```

Probably the most interesting part of my answer will be to tell you to refer to [Casting and Type Conversions (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx) for a full explanation of the different type of conversions in C#, and secondly to [Conversion Operators (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/09479473.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Implicit and explicit type conversion in C# is similiar to C++ and aother OOP languages.

If the conversion is not going to cause any dataloss, conversion will occur automatically.  Nothing else needs to be done.:

```
int i = 10;
double j = 20.1;

j = i;

// j = 10.
```

if the conversion will cause dataloss, then you must explicitly state the type that the subject will be converted to:

```
int i = 10;
double j = 20.1;

i = (int) j;

// i = 10
```

This is the most basic example, other conversions will occur when you work cast objects according to their intheritance tree...

Comment: Note that there are a small number of **data losing** implicit conversions. The conversion from long to double, for example, is *data losing* but not *magnitude losing*.

Answer (score 0):

**Built in types:**

```
byte smallNumber = 255;

// byte implicitly casted to int
int num = smallNumber;

// explicitly cast byte to int
num = (int)smallNumber;
```

**Custom types:**

```
public abstract class AnimalBase
public sealed class Tiger : AnimalBase

Tiger tiger = new Tiger();

// explicit (but really does not required to be specified)
AnimalBase anotherAnimal = (AnimalBase)tiger;

// implicit Tiger to AnimalBase
AnimalBase anotherAnimal = tiger;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume that we have a 1 lit empty bottle and a 1/2 lit bottle.Suppose I want to transfer the water from second bottle to the first bottle.As as the 1st container is bigger ,it is capable to contain the whole water.
e.g.

```
int i=10; //i is 4 bytes. 
long l=i;//l is 8 bytes.
```

This type of conversion is called Implicit conversion.
Suppose we are transferring the whole water from big container to small container.Then there is a chance of loosing data and also the code will not be executed.
e.g.

```
long l=199;
int i=(int)l;
```

//till when the capacity of int value is satisfying it is possible to copy.
This is called Explicit Conversion